# zsh: abort pipenv shell

Tags: python, django, heroku, pipenv

On attempts to install psycopg2, postgresql, django-Heroku, gunicorn, I am now getting the below error. Unable to successfully run pipenv shell or pipenv install; can't run python manage.py runserver, which means I can't open my project! Appreciate anyone who can reach out with fix for this issue.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_3/libexec/bin/python3.8
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      pipenv shell
```

Comment: Add more info on what command you are executing.

Comment: i just ran brew install awscli and

Comment: Result: The "examples" directory has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/awscli/examples

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions and functions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/awscli/2.0.0_1: 10,439 files, 74.8MB

Comment: what would I install next?

Comment: Just ran pipenv shell
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.7, but you are using None (/Users/username/.local/share/v/d/bin/python).
  $ pipenv --rm and rebuilding the virtual environment may resolve the issue.
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
 . /Users/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/

Comment: brew install python3
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python-3.7.7.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d5c5dab29177045462f7286e90815417d835b90d645c0331cf1028c0c79c3bd8--python-3.7.7.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-3.7.7.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks...

Comment: I still get the original abort error when I run pipenv shell again: 
Shell for /Users/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-multiple-choice-username-ADdgTIno already activated.
No action taken to avoid nested environments.
python manage.py runserver: 
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-multiple-choice-username-ADdgTIno/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

i think pipenv in not properly installed. try
`brew install pipenv` # if you have brew installed
`pip3 install pipenv` # if you don't have brew installed